# What is the correct way to make MongoDB Atlas connection available in middleware functions in Node.js/Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-atlas

**Environment**

Node.js (`18 LTS`) / Express (`^4.18.2`)
MongoDB Native Driver (`^4.12.0`)
MongoDB Atlas (`5.0.14`)

*Application Structure*

```
.github  
config  
 - mongodb_client.js  
dist  
middleware  
node_modules  
routes  
src
views
.env  
.gitignore
app.js  
package.json  
README.md
```

*Connection Code*

As a sanity check, this is the connection code that is provided in the MongoDB Atlas interface:

*As a screenshot:*
[image]

*As code:*

```js
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');

const uri = "mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@cluster0.******.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });

client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});
```

**Desired Behaviour**

The code snippet provided in the MongoDB Atlas interface performs the connection and subsequent database calls in one file.

However, I would like to:

- Create a file that contains the MongoDB Atlas connection (e.g `mongodb_client.js`)
- Export the connection so that it can be used in middleware files (e.g `my_middleware_01.js`)

So, in pseudo code, I imagine it would look something like this:

*config / mongodb_client.js*

```js
import { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } from 'mongodb'; 

const connection_string = process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING;

const mongodb_client = new MongoClient(connection_string, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });

// export the connection somehow   
export { mongodb_client };
```

*middleware / my_middleware_01.js*

```js
import { mongodb_client } from '../config/mongodb_client.js';

const api_myResource_get = async (req, res) => {
    mongodb_client.open();
    let collection = mongodb_client.db('myDatabase').collection('myCollection');
    let result = await collection.findOne(query, options);  
    res.json({ result: result });
    mongodb_client.close();  
}; 

export { api_myResource_get };
```

**What I've Tried**

It seems I was grappling with this dynamic over a year ago and posted my solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70135909

However, I think that conventions have changed since then.

For example when instantiating the client,  the current method seems to be:

```js
const client = new MongoClient(connection_string, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });
```

whereas previously it was something like:

```js
await MongoClient.connect(connection_string);
```

I've Google searched:

> how to make mongodb connection available in node.js middleware?

But all the results seem to reference this older convention and I'd like to ensure I am using best practice (and most recent conventions).

**Related Questions and Resources**

[Passing Mongo DB Object DB to Express Middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794107/passing-mongo-db-object-db-to-express-middleware)

[What is best way to handle global connection of Mongodb in NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397608/what-is-best-way-to-handle-global-connection-of-mongodb-in-nodejs)

[How do I manage MongoDB connections in a Node.js web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656574/how-do-i-manage-mongodb-connections-in-a-node-js-web-application)

[What is the difference between MongoClient and the client object which we get in the callback of MongoClient.connect() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889278/what-is-the-difference-between-mongoclient-and-the-client-object-which-we-get-in)

[How to properly reuse connection to Mongodb across NodeJs application and modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621940/how-to-properly-reuse-connection-to-mongodb-across-nodejs-application-and-module)

[MongoDB Driver Connection Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/driver-connection/)

**EDIT 01:**

Below is one attempt which is returning the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'db')

*config / mongodb_connection.js*

```js
import { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } from 'mongodb'; 

const connection_string = process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING;

class mongodb_connection {
  static async open() {
    if (this.conn) return this.conn;
    this.conn = await MongoClient.connect(connection_string, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });
    return this.conn;
  }
}

mongodb_connection.conn = null;
mongodb_connection.url = connection_string;

export { mongodb_connection };
```

*middleware / api_mongodb_get.js*

```js
import { mongodb_connection } from '../../config/mongodb_connection.js';

const api_mongodb_get = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        mongodb_connection.open();
        const collection = mongodb_connection.conn.db('pages').collection('pages');
        const result = await collection.findOne({ "my_key": "my value" }); 

        res.json({ data: result });
        mongodb_connection.close();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }

};

export { api_mongodb_get };
```

**EDIT 02:**

The following 'works' but I don't know if it is best practice or not.

In other words, I don't know if I am overlooking something that will cause undesired behavior.

*config / mongodb_connection.js*

```
import { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } from 'mongodb'; 

const connection_string = process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING;

const mongodb_connection = new MongoClient(connection_string, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });

export { mongodb_connection };
```

*middleware / api_mongodb_get.js*

```js
import { mongodb_connection } from '../../config/mongodb_connection.js';

const api_mongodb_get = async (req, res) => {

    try {
            mongodb_connection.connect(async err => {  

                const collection = mongodb_connection.db('pages').collection('pages');
                const result = await collection.findOne({ "my_key": "my value" }); 

                res.json({ data: result });
                
                mongodb_connection.close();
            });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }

};

export { api_mongodb_get };
```

Comment: `MongoClient.connect()` [still exists](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.13/classes/MongoClient.html#connect). I also don't see much wrong with your own posted solution, and I wonder if any answers to your question ("what is the current best practice?") won't just be opinion-based (and therefore OT).

Comment: You are correct, `MongoClient.connect()` does still exist.  I made an error.  I have added two attempts to the end of my question - one doesn't work and one does, although I am not sure if it is best practice.  When I use the term 'best practice' - I mean it in the concrete sense of 1) Am I overlooking recent changes in convention and 2)  Am I doing something that is blatantly wrong and will cause problems with pooling or connection management etc.

Comment: In your "EDIT 01" attempt, you're not awaiting the call to `mongodb_connection.open()` which is causing the error. AFAIK, the MongoDB driver will handle connections internally so you don't need to use open/close for every query.

Answer (score -1):

Insetead of using **mongodb**, use **mongoose** library to establish the connection.
Here is an example to establish the connection with mongodb cluster:

connectDb.js:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const DB_URL = process.env.DB_URL;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDb = async () => {
    try {
        const connection = await mongoose.connect(DB_URL)
        console.log(`Connected to database Successfully: ${connection}`)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
module.exports = connectDb;
```

and I think I don't need to mention that the DB_URL is the URL which is provided by the mondodb cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I do not want to use Mongoose (it is a whole layer of abstraction that I don't need and I prefer to work with the native driver).

Comment: He asked for a specific implementation of a piece of software. Not your personal recommendation.

Comment: He asked for a specific implementation of a piece of software. Not your personal recommendation.